# How to replace &quot in CSS with ""

Tags: html, css

How do I replace `&quot;` with `""`?

I'm currently trying to achieve executing the following CSS code:

```
@font-face{
font-family:"Segoe UI Semilight";
src:url(segoeuisl.ttf);
}
```

However on the browser when I expect element the below `:&quot` is getting added and not appropriate `""` therefore I was wondering how to execute the above or escape the `:&quot`?

```
@font-face{
font-family:&quot;Segoe UI Semilight&quot;;
src:url(segoeuisl.ttf);
}
```

Comment: Where is your CSS coming from?  Browsers will not convert `&quot;` to `""` within CSS files or within the `<style>` elements

Answer (score 0):

why is this :&quot added? Is this done by e.g. webpack?

If this is just a simple CSS file?
Try to change the charset to UTF-8.
If you are using Notepad++ you can do this by clicking selecting Encoding in the Menubar.

PS: It could also be a problem with your webserver or the browser itself, but I would check the charset first.

BR
Marc

Comment: There are too many questions for this to be an answer.  Better to ask the OP via comments... which I realise is ironic as you are 1 point (at the time of writing) short of the 50 rep needed to do that... so I will not flag in this case

Comment: "There are too many questions for this to be an answer." Ok good to know, but what do you mean by this? Isn´t this a clear idea?

Comment: An answer needs to be exactly that... an answer.  If you need to get clarification from the OP then you do it via comments, otherwise you're just guessing.  Again, the irony is that you need 50 rep to comment on other peoples posts, so probably best keeping to answering question you can give a definitive answer to so your rep increases

Comment: Guys I have a simple CSS file and just want to replace &quot; with ", the browser adds &quot

Comment: I believe I need to escape the quote?

Comment: Is it a public page? I´m not sure why any browser should to something like this.

Comment: What you mean by public page? @m.Schroder

Comment: How would I escape the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

it's able by this code, but I think, better is directly replace `&quot;` in source code.

```
const folder = path.join(__dirname, 'site');
const cssfilepath = path.join(folder, 'style.css');
      cssfilepath = path.normalize(cssfilepath);
const cssfile = fs.readFileSync(cssfilepath, 'utf8');
const modified = cssfile.replace(
    /&quot;/,
    `"`
);
```